# Boolean return types on Abstract methods of Activity

Tags: java, android

I want to understand what exactly the boolean return types do while implementing some abstract methods in android. For eg :

```
Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        MyCurrentScreen.this.finish();
    }

    return true;
}
```

The functionality also works fine if I change the return type to false. Upon my understanding, the implementation of abstract method does not return to its caller even (Correct me if this is not the case), but, If this is the case, why there is a need for the return type here ?

Comment: this is exactly described in the API....beginners should look here first...https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)

Comment: It's true that it's in the API docs but I disagree that beginners should look there first. The word choice for beginners is often quite abstract (hehe). `This hook is called whenever...` What does hook mean here? `calling the item's Runnable or sending a message to its Handler as appropriate...` What is the item's Runnable? What is its Handler?

Comment: why don't you read the method documentation?

Comment: well I understand that it is sometimes heavy to understand, but learning is always difficult and most things are self explaining if you dive deep into the context. If you are a developer, learning never stops...

Answer (score 1):

Abstract methods may return to it's caller. Like any other method.

Then (from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem):

> This hook is called whenever an item in your options menu is selected.
>   The default implementation simply returns false to have the normal
>   processing happen (calling the item's Runnable or sending a message to
>   its Handler as appropriate). You can use this method for any items for
>   which you would like to do processing without those other facilities.

Return `true` to consume the event